# Magento 2 checkout form: how to add custom field?

Tags: checkout, magento2

How to add custom field to Shipping Address form in Magento 2 **Onepage Checkout**?

For example:

> add select box like "Country" below phone number field

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create new customer address attribute and map this attribute by xml. So after attribute creation create **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="customer_country" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">400</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="custom_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">410</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Read more about this from [here](https://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/how-to-add-custom-field-to-shipping-address-form-in-magento-2-onepage-checkout/)

You can download example module from [Here](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-checkoutadditionalfield)

Comment: But that adds an INPUT element. What if I need a SELECT element? I cannot do it at the moment.

Comment: How about if you need to map that form field (ie checkbox for opt-in) to customer attribute instead of customer address attribute?

Comment: @sohel-rana  I need to add new text field into the default shipping address form. I tried your module and it added 2 fields, but those fields were added at the end of the existing form. How can I put my new field inside the existing form? (Ex: my new field is RefererName and I want to put it after **Company** and **Street Address**) , How can I do that?

And if I wanted to add more fields, how can I modify LayoutProcessor.php from your module?

Comment: i have created an extension for that but not working... can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial I found for adding delivery date. For other datatypes, like select or test, you can change that in the LayoutProcessorPlugin.

http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

You can also avoid using Observers by hooking into the OrderRepository and writing a beforeSave function.